# Draw more than one widget in QListView item

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I created my own data model based on `QAbstractListModel` and connected it with QListView by simple `ui->listView->setModel(prodModel)` - it works fine.

Now I want to create custom view in QListView for each item. For example, I want to reach that every data row from model will be shown in style like Stack Overflow (question with rating). I want to use Qt widgets and **arrange** it on my own idea - using layouts etc.

Unfortunately, a Qt's guide about model/view doesn't have described how to use `QItemDelegate` to show my widgets - I'm not interested about editing data in view (but I want to interact like click - ideally if I could click and get signal/sth in each widget in my custom view).

I found some examples, but they describe drawing only one widget (QProgressBar) without any layouts.

Any help will be appreciable, thanks!

Comment: Do you want the item of the ListView to be the view to which you can add widgets?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov my goal is possibility to add my custom widget to ListView and good way to interact with embedded buttons etc. inside it. This is easy using QListWidget, but I'll lose model architecture, which is very useful. Currently, I can use delegate to edit value on double click, but I don't know how display my widget all time.

Comment: Ok, lets imagine that you want each item in the ListView to look like StackOverflow question with rating. You can inherit from ItemDelegate and reimplement paint() method where you will actually draw what you want(without layouting, just simple drawing) . Then you will also reimplement editorEvent from where you will emit singals based on clicked position. That can be possible solution of your problem.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov yes, but my problem is that I don't know how to draw Qt's UI elements inside paint() method, only primitives. I want to use QLabel, QButton etc.

Comment: Have a look at the example with progress bar. You can also draw some controls within paint function http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#details

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov thanks for this link, I don't know how, but I didn't find it. I'll try it.